# Error while trying to generate a jspdf with html2canvas

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using react and I'm trying to make a pdf with html2canvas and jspdf.
I want to give in input to html2canvas a  that I make at the moment.
When I try to make the pdf I get this error:

```
 index.ts:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document
```

Here is the code:

```
 const input = (<div><h2>Test</h2></div>);
html2canvas(input).then((canvas)=>{
  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);

    pdf.save("download.pdf")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`html2canvas` accepts DOM elements but in your case `input` is not attached to the DOM.

if in case you want to generate custom template as pdf then you can do `var node = document.createElement("div"); node.appendChild(yourElement)` & hide it (if needed) from the dom by mentioning position fixed and top:-5000px and then use that for generating pdf

documentation: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started

Comment: I get this error when I try to appendChild: TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: try `var node = document.createElement("div"); node.appendChild(yourElement);`

Comment: I get the same error on the line where I do node.appendChild

Comment: Now it works, I created the node var and then I set node.innerHTML = myHtmlString, then I added the node to the document with document.body.appendChild(node) and in the Html2canvas I set as input node

Comment: If I set the style of the div to make it appear outside the screen, when I make the pdf the div is outside too, how can I do it?

Comment: there's `onclone` callback available which can be used to modify contents of cloned html.

Comment: Documentation: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration